# Retrieving images into HTML with Swift

Tags: html, swift, image, pdf

I'm really struggling with getting swift saved images into HTML.
I'm taking a photo, saving it into default documents folder and then i want to take them out and put into HTML string which later turns into PDF. Last thing what i need is to get saved images into HTML.. Does anybody know how to do this?

Here's my image save function:

```
private func saveImage(imageData: Data, named: String, completion: @escaping (URL) -> Void) {
        guard let directory = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false) as NSURL else {
            return
        }
        do {
            try imageData.write(to: directory.appendingPathComponent(named)!)
            completion(directory.appendingPathComponent(named)! as URL)
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
    }
```

After that I'm putting into HTML this:

`"<td class='unit'>" + "/(url.absoluteString).png" + "</td></tr>"`

It actually is the full path to the image, but I guess it doesn't work like that and unfortunately ending up like this:

[Image with the resulting PDF after html rendering/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNyjV.png)

Comment: I would have put `url.path` instead of `url.absoluteString`. How do you transform your HTML String into PDF? See https://github.com/nyg/HTMLWithImagesToPDF ?

Comment: Gonna try, thanks! Here You go bruh, I used this: https://github.com/radianttap/HTML2PDFRenderer

Answer (score 0):

You must put the path into an image (img) tag.

```
"<td class='unit'><img src='/(url.absoluteString).png' /></td></tr>"
```

Comment: `
<td class='unit'><img src='file:///Users/sosa/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/000C179D-DAB2-4647-B095-0B021843F5AB/data/Containers/Data/Application/34141CA2-B12B-46D1-80C2-8F6FE1E95E80/Documents/5.png' /></td></tr>
`
Aw maan, prayed this to work. Still nothing man :/

Maybe I should strip the 'file:' off?